# How can I add the time back to the system tray?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma, system-tray

I accidently removed the time from the system tray while playing with some settings.  I want to add it back, however, it seems that there is no way to do so.  How can I do this?

I have tried going to "configure system tray" and then Entries.  However, there is no way to add a new entry, you can only configure the ones that are there.  Time is not an entry.

I have tried creating a new system tray, but it also doesn't have the time.

Kubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [an old thread](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=37982), but possibly it helps.  .. in short:

1. Cashew
2. Add Widgets
3. Select desired clock widget

Comment: Yep, that's it, thanks.  The clock is actually a seperate widget and not part of the system tray.  That was the mistake that I made.  Thanks.